# how to get my integer to word dictionary function works correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was able to make this function converts integer to words in some cases, but still have trouble when the input is above 120; for 121,122,,,, and anything above ..20 after that, ie, 221,233,etc.. It returns one hundred None(for case above 120). And it would not work if the input is over 1020.

```
def int_to_word(n):
    d={0:'zero',1:'one',2:'two',3:'three',4:'four',5:'five',
      6:'six',7:'seven',8:'eight',9:'nine',10:'ten',
      11:'eleven',12:'twelve',13:'thirteen',14:'fourteen',
      15:'fifteen',16:'sixteen',17:'seventeen',18:'eighteen',
      19:'nineteen',20:'twenty',30:'thirty',40:'forty',
      50:'fifty',60:'sixty',70:'seventy',80:'eighty',
      90:'ninety'}
    k=1000
    m=k*1000
    if (n <20):
        print(d.get(n))
    elif (n >=20 and n <100):
        if n%10==0:
            print(d.get(n))
        else:
            print(d.get(n//10*10),d.get(n%10),end="")
    elif (n>=100) and (n<k):
        if n%100==0:
            print(d[n//100],end=" ")
            print("hundred")
        else :
            print(d.get(n//100),"hundred",d.get(n%100),end="")
    elif (n>=k)and (n<m):
        if n%k==0:
            print(d.get(n//k),end=" ")
            print("thousand")
        else:
            print(d.get(n//k),end=" ")
            print("thousand",end=" ")
            print(d.get(n%k))

int_to_word(n)
```

Comment: I suggest you try having the function return a string, instead of printing one, and use recursion.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the code working correctly using return and running recursive.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like homework, so I will hint rather than completely provide your answer.

Please note that (in US English) handling "thousand" is *exactly* the same as handling numbers less than 1,000. The same is true (in US English) for 10E6 (million), 10E9 (billion), 10E12 (trillion), etc. I understand that this is different in Indian English, with lakhs and what-not. Also in countries that consider 10E9 = "thousand million" and 10E12 = "billion." So you will definitely want to tune your answer to whatever your instructor expects.

Anyway, 107,000 is "one hundred seven **thousand**", and 123,456 is "one hundred twenty three **thousand** four hundred fifty six."

You can see that this is a chance for a loop, because the logic is identical each time through.

With that said, you will have to focus on the part of the number less than 1,000. The hundreds part is fairly easy: 401 is "four hundred one", and 525 is "five hundred twenty five", so all you need to do is check for a significant hundreds digit and add/not add the appropriate text.

Next, we come down to the tens and ones digits. Looking at your code, you have way too much logic. I recommend you explicitly separate out the various parts, so you know what you are dealing with:

```
hundreds = (n % 1000) // 100
tens_ones = n % 100
```

Now you can ask: is `tens_ones` in `d`? If so, you're done. If not, you'll have to divide it down into a tens part (and multiply by 10 to get back to 30 or whatever, which is in `d`), and a ones part which will be in `d`.

Answer (score 0):

For your code, I think the problem is that you didn't consider how to handle the **hundreds** and **thousands** numbers correctly. And your code is only handle the number which is **less than** 1000,000. Here is the modified code based on your idea:

```
def int_to_word(n):
d={0:'zero',1:'one',2:'two',3:'three',4:'four',5:'five',
  6:'six',7:'seven',8:'eight',9:'nine',10:'ten',
  11:'eleven',12:'twelve',13:'thirteen',14:'fourteen',
  15:'fifteen',16:'sixteen',17:'seventeen',18:'eighteen',
  19:'nineteen',20:'twenty',30:'thirty',40:'forty',
  50:'fifty',60:'sixty',70:'seventy',80:'eighty',
  90:'ninety'}
k=1000
m=k*1000
if (n <20):
    print(d.get(n))
elif (n >=20 and n <100):
    if n%10==0:
        print(d.get(n))
    else:
        print(d.get(n//10*10),d.get(n%10),end="")
elif (n>=100) and (n<k):
    if n%100==0:
        print(d[n//100],end=" ")
        print("hundred")
    else :
        print(d.get(n//100),"hundred",d.get(n%100//10*10),d.get(n%100%10),end=" ")
elif (n>=k)and (n<m):
    if n%k==0:
        print(d.get(n//k//10*10),d.get(n//k%10),end=" ")
        print("thousand")
    else:
        if n//k > 100:
            print(d.get(n//k//100),end=" ")
            print("hundred",end=" ")
            print(d.get(n//k%100//10*10),d.get(n//k%100%10),end=" ")
            print("thousand",end=" ")
        elif n//k >10:
            print(d.get(n//k//10*10),d.get(n//k%10),end=" ")
            print("thousand",end=" ")
        else:
            print(d.get(n//k%10),end=" ")
            print("thousand",end=" ")
        print(d.get(n%k//100),"hundred",d.get(n%k%100//10*10),d.get(n%k%100%10),end=" ")
```

In [2]:int_to_word(999999)

nine hundred ninety nine thousand nine hundred ninety nine

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get this code working correctly using return statement and recursive.